# Go race detector: How to set log_path on Windows?

Tags: go

I am using the Go race detector on Windows and would like the detected races to be logged to a file rather than to stderr. This is possible by [setting the `GORACE` environment variable](https://golang.org/doc/articles/race_detector.html#Options):

```
$ GORACE='log_path=/var/reports/myprogram' ./myprogram
```

However, when trying it on Windows my program writes an error to stderr and immediately exits:

```
PS C:\foo> $env:GORACE = 'log_path=C:\RaceReports\myprogram'
PS C:\foo> .\myprogram.exe
ERROR: expected '='
PS C:\foo>
```

It works fine if I don't use absolute paths:

```
PS C:\foo> $env:GORACE = 'log_path=myprogram'
PS C:\foo> .\myprogram.exe
PS C:\foo> ls


    Directory: C:\foo


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       15/11/2017     17:17            581 myprogram.7904
-a----       15/11/2017     16:55        2599936 myprogram.exe


PS C:\foo>
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is this a bug in Go? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The backslashes may be interpreted as escape chars, so try doubling them "C:\\RaceReports\\myprogram", or try with forward slashes instead which may be auto-translated to backslashes internally. (Not posting as an answer since I'm not certain if either of these will actually work.)

Comment: The `$env:` syntax isn't familiar to me. What version of Windows is this? Does `set GORACE='log_path=C:\RaceReports\myprogram'` work?

Comment: @bishop: Windows PowerShell: [Creating – and Modifying -- Environment Variables](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730964.aspx) For example, `$env:TestVariable = "This is a test environment variable."`.